# webapi: Error CS0029

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

> Error CS0029  **Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue' to
>   'System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue'**

I am in **.net Core**,

the code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCompanies()
{

     var resp = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new 
    StringContent("[{\"Name\":\"ABC\"},[{\"A\":\"1\"},{\"B\":\"2\"},
    {\"C\":\"3\"}]]", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json") };


    resp.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return resp;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core does not use `HttpResponseMessage` on the server side. You need to update your syntax.

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetCompanies() {
    var json = "[{\"Name\":\"ABC\"},[{\"A\":\"1\"},{\"B\":\"2\"},{\"C\":\"3\"}]]";
    return Content(json, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```